# Why does nesting the induction tactic also nest the inductive hypotheses under a lambda?

Tags: coq

```
Theorem mult_comm : forall m n : nat,
  m * n = n * m.
Proof.
intros.
induction n.
- simpl. rewrite (mult_0_r m). reflexivity.
- simpl.
  rewrite <- IHn.
  induction m.
    simpl. reflexivity.
    simpl.
```

The above is from the Software Foundation's second chapter.

```
1 subgoal
m, n : nat
IHn : S m * n = n * S m
IHm : m * n = n * m -> m * S n = m + m * n
______________________________________(1/1)
S (n + m * S n) = S (m + (n + m * n))
```

I am really confused as to what `IHm` is supposed to be here. The way I understand it, Coq tactics get compiled under the hood to some functional program, but I am really not sure what is going on here. I am pretty sure that this is not I intended it to do.

What I wanted to do is something like the following Idris program.

```
add_comm : {a,b : Nat} -> a + b = b + a
add_assoc : {a,b,c : Nat} -> (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)

total
mult_comm : {m,n : Nat} -> (m * n) = n * m
mult_comm {m = Z} {n = Z} = Refl
mult_comm {m = Z} {n = (S k)} = mult_comm {m=Z} {n=k}
mult_comm {m = (S k)} {n = Z} = mult_comm {m=k} {n=Z}
mult_comm {m = (S k)} {n = (S j)} = 
    let prf1 = mult_comm {m=k} {n=S j}
        prf2 = mult_comm {m=S k} {n=j}
        prf3 = mult_comm {m=k} {n=j}
        prf_add_comm = add_comm {a=k} {b=j}
        prf_add_assoc = add_assoc {a=k} {b=j} {c=j*k}
        prf_add_assoc' = add_assoc {a=j} {b=k} {c=j*k} 
    in
        rewrite prf1 in
        rewrite sym prf2 in
        rewrite prf3 in
        rewrite sym prf_add_assoc in
        rewrite sym prf_add_assoc' in
        rewrite (add_comm {a=k} {b=j}) in
        Refl
```

More specifically, I need `prf1`, `prf2` and `prf3` which I get using recursive calls to `mult_comm`. In Coq the two of the proofs are stuck in a lambda and I am not sure how that happened. I see that Coq's `induction` tactic is not doing what I think it should be doing.

In addition to the explanation of the above, let me also ask is there more introductory material to Coq than Software Foundations just in case I get stuck like this again on some tactic? Note that I know how to solve this in Coq as I've found the solution online.

I've tried tackling the SF book unsuccessfully back in 2016 as an introduction to dependently typed programming and now with the benefit of hindsight, I see that Little Typer and the Idris book are much better in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `induction` tactic, Coq uses heuristics to determine the predicate `P : nat -> Prop` that you want to prove by induction. Before calling `induction` for the second time, the proof state looks like this:

```
  m, n : nat
  IHn : m * n = n * m
  ============================
  m * S n = m + m * n
```

What happened is that Coq decided to include the premise `IHn` in the induction predicate, which was inferred to be

```
P m := m * n = n * m -> m * S n = m + m * n
```

which is exactly what you had in your induction hypothesis. In this case, you could argue that it was silly for Coq to use the premise, but there are cases where dropping it would result in an unprovable goal.  For instance, consider the following proof attempt:

```
Lemma double_inj : forall n m, n + n = m + m -> n = m.
Proof.
  intros n m H.
  induction n as [|n IH].
  (* ... *)
```

If `H` were dropped after calling `induction`, you would have to prove `forall n m, n = m`, which clearly does not hold.

This example is one of the reasons why it is often a bad idea to call `induction` multiple times in a single Coq proof.  As we suggest in that exercise in Software Foundations, it is better to prove an auxiliary lemma, since you can be explicit about the induction predicate. For this example, there are other options as well.  You could, for instance, call `clear IHn` to drop the `IHn` premise, which would lead Coq to the correct predicate. The ssreflect proof language, which now ships with Coq, has a different tactic for performing induction called `elim`, which allows you to be more explicit in the choice of the  predicate.

I agree with your final comment, but I should add that it is not the goal of Software Foundations to be an introduction to dependently typed programming. Though Coq supports this paradigm, it is generally cumbersome to write such programs directly, and much easier to use tactics to prove lemmas about simply typed programs. For instance, your proof of `mult_comm` is accepted by Idris because its termination checker is smart enough to recognize all recursive calls as decreasing, even though they are not decreasing with respect to a fixed argument (in the second clause, `n` decreases, whereas in the third `m` does). This is not possible in Coq, and you must split the definition into multiple recursive functions, one for each argument, or use well-founded induction on pairs of natural numbers, which would be overkill for this example.

Adam Chlipala has another Coq textbook called [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) that you might want to check out. However, I don't think you will find a comprehensive description of Coq's tactics there, either. Like `induction`, many tactics rely on heuristics and are hard to explain in detail.

On a final note, Matthieu Sozeau has developed a package called [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) that makes dependently typed programming in Coq much closer to Idris or Agda. If you find this style of proving more intuitive, you could try to use it.

Comment: With standard `induction`, you can also control which parts of the context goes into the predicate with the [`in`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.induction) clause. In the proof of `mult_comm`, `induction m in |- *` correctly ignores `IHn`.